# From linear invariants of group to general ones

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, invariant-theory

There is a lot of information about classical/linear invariants of finite groups.

But does it lead to general invariants of group (for example, when we consider some action of our group on finite set)? And, if the answer is yes - how can these invariants can be derived (like invariants of action Rubic's rotations on the Rubic's cube configurations, or parity invariants in 15 puzzle)?

In particular, I need general invariants of the product of two symmetric groups.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an invariant here?

Comment: Suppose $G$ acts on $X.$ Then invariant is function $f\colon X \to Y$ with $f(gx) = x$ for all $x \in X$ and $g \in G.$

Comment: Okay. I don't really understand what you want to know about these.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! $f(gx) = f(x)$!

Comment: I still don't understand. What is there to say in this level of generality?

Comment: You know that parity invariant explains 15 puzzle nonequivalent configurations, several finite invariants explains Rubics cube nonequivalent configurations. So there are some positive developments in this direction. Also first of all I need to know about finite case (group and underlying set are finite).